# Uncatchable Null Byte csv.Error Exception

Tags: python-3.x, csv, exception

I'm trying to catch a Null Byte Exception in the last line of a CSV file:

```
def Catch(csv_filename):
    with open(csv_filename,'r+') as File:
        File_reader = csv.reader(File,delimiter="\t",dialect='excel-tab')
        a = []
        for row in File_reader:
            try:
                a.append(row)
            except csv.Error:
                return "Error"

Catch("/../DataLogger.csv")
```

but an _csv.Error is raised:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/../test.py", line 21, in <module>
Catch("/../DataLogger.csv")
File "/../test.py", line 13, in Catch
for row in File_reader:
    _csv.Error: line contains NULL byte
```

I don't get why the exception is not catched with the function.
I'm using python 3.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that's because the exception occurs as soon as your code reaches the `for` statement.

No exception can happen in the `a.append` line, the `csv` module does its job in the iteration of the `for` loop.

Once you know that, the fix is trivial:

```
try:
   for row in File_reader:
       a.append(row)
except csv.Error:
    return "Error"
```

note that one could be tempted to use direct conversion to list: `a = list(File_reader)` but since the exception would take place in the `list` conversion, `a` wouldn't be filled, which would be a nuisance if the start of the file contains useful data you want to read (but since you're returning an error string, it doesn't seem to matter here)

Comment: I found that `_csv.Error` is raised even before iterating the content of `csv.reader`. For example: `reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=options.get('csv_separator', ','))` raises if csvfile contains null byte.

Answer (score 1):

```
def Catch(csv_filename):
    with open(csv_filename,'r+') as File:
        try:
            File_reader = csv.reader(File,delimiter="\t",dialect='excel-tab')
            a = []
            for row in File_reader:
                a.append(row)
        except csv.Error
            return "Error"

Catch("/../DataLogger.csv")
```

The whole parsing has to be inside Try/catch, instead of only `a.append`.